# Magento2 - add dropdown city everywhere in store

Tags: magento2, module, dropdown-attribute, drop-downs

Magento2 - I want to show city in dropdown for everwhere in store. I was tried with https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown but its not working properly.

Comment: You can try this https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-city-dropdown

Comment: @PradipGarchar its paid module.